# code accounting for multiple delimiters isn't working

Tags: c, arrays, string, delimiter

I have a program I wrote to take a string of words and, based on the delimiter that appears, separate each word and add it to an array.

I've adjusted it to account for either a ' ' , '.'  or '.'. Now the goal is to adjust for multiple delimiters appearing together (as in "the dog,,,was walking") and still only add the word. While my program works, and it doesn't print out extra delimiters, every time it encounters additional delimiters, it includes a space in the output instead of ignoring them.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char *givenString = "USA,Canada,Mexico,Bermuda,Grenada,Belize";

    int stringCharCount;

    //get length of string to allocate enough memory for array
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        if (givenString[i] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
        else {
            stringCharCount++;
        }
    }



    // counting # of commas in the original string
    int commaCount = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < stringCharCount; i++) {
        if (givenString[i] == ',' || givenString[i] == '.' || givenString[i] == ' ') {
            commaCount++;
        }
    }


    //declare blank Array that is the length of commas (which is the number of elements in the original string)
    //char *finalArray[commaCount];



    int z = 0;
    char *finalArray[commaCount] ;
    char *wordFiller = malloc(stringCharCount);


    int j = 0;
    char current = ' ';

    for (int i = 0; i <= stringCharCount; i++) {

        if (((givenString[i] == ',' || givenString[i] == '\0' || givenString[i] == ',' || givenString[i] == ' ') && (current != (' ' | '.' | ',')))) {
            finalArray[z] = wordFiller;
            wordFiller = malloc(stringCharCount);
            j=0;
            z++;
            current = givenString[i];
        }

        else {
            wordFiller[j++] = givenString[i];
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < commaCount; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", finalArray[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This program took me hours and hours to get together (with help from more experienced developers) and I can't help but get frustrated. I'm using the debugger to my best ability but definitely need more experience with it.

/////////

I went back to pad and paper and kind of rewrote my code. Now I'm trying to store delimiters in an array and compare the elements of that array to the current string value. If they are equal, then we have come across a new word and we add it to the final string array. I'm struggling to figure out the placement and content of the "for" loop that I would use for this.

```
    char * original = "USA,Canada,Mexico,Bermuda,Grenada,Belize";

    //creating two intialized variables to count the number of characters and elements to add to the array (so we can allocate enough mmemory)
    int stringCharCount = 0;
    //by setting elementCount to 1, we can account for the last word that comes after the last comma
    int elementCount = 1;

    //calculate value of stringCharCount and elementCount to allocate enough memory for temporary word storage and for final array
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        if (original[i] == '\0') {
            break;
        }
        else {
            stringCharCount++;
            if (original[i] == ',') {
                elementCount++;
            }
        }
    }

    //account for the final element
    elementCount = elementCount;

    char *tempWord = malloc(stringCharCount);
    char *finalArray[elementCount];
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    //int c = 0;
    //char *delimiters[4] = {".", ",", " ", "\0"};

        for (int i = 0; i <= stringCharCount; i++) {
            if (original[i] == ',' || original[i] == '\0') {
                finalArray[a] = tempWord;
                tempWord = malloc(stringCharCount);
                tempWord[b] = '\0';
                b = 0;
                a++;
            }
            else {
                tempWord[b++] = original[i];
            }
            }

    for (int i = 0; i < elementCount; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", finalArray[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: better: `int stringCharCount = strlen(givenString);`

Comment: @karan, it is difficult to help somebody with a particular problem if they don't have a basic understanding of what the code is doing. The issue is that the `for` where you do the `wordFiller` will never enter, because your `current` variable is a ' ', and you have a && operator, for the test, that will always come back as false, and never enter that block of code.

Comment: also: `wordFiller = malloc(stringCharCount);` will allocate way too few bytes.

Comment: also: `current != (' ' | '.' | ',')` that is not the way `C` works.

Comment: @DrKoch why would it allocate too few bytes? wordFiller resets every time it loops through, adding the next word from the original string to it. strCharCount will allow it to store up to 40 characters, and wordFiller never stores more than 7 bytes (Bermuda or Grenada)

Comment: I've been programming for about...2 and a half weeks now. I understand that it's beneficial for me to write down everything on paper and then translate to code...I know what I want to do on paper. My difficulty is with the latter part.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I confused stringCharCount and commaCount

Comment: @DrKoch My instructor has now told me to include an array full of whatever delimiters I want. The idea is to now loop through that array and compare each of them to the current index value of the original string. If they aren't equal, I can add characters to my temporary string "wordFiller", but if they are equal, I append the contents of wordFiller to my new array, reset wordFiller, and run through the previous loop again.

Comment: I think having to do this may force me to clean up my code a bit. I'm going to write the whole problem out on paper and see if I can make it much neater. Hopefully this will make it so that I can easily change the program as I see fit...I need to restructure the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Many issues.  Suggest dividing code into small pieces and debug those first.

--

Un-initialize data.

```
// int stringCharCount;
int stringCharCount = 0;
... 
stringCharCount++;
```

Or

```
int stringCharCount  = strlen(givenString);
```

Other problems too: `finalArray[]` is never assigned a terminarting null character yet `printf("%s\n", finalArray[i]);` used.

Unclear use of `char *`

```
char *wordFiller = malloc(stringCharCount);

wordFiller = malloc(stringCharCount);
```

Comment: unfortunately, I can't use strlen. Some built-in functions aren't allowed here.

Comment: @karan satia Recommend then to create your own helper function `ks_strlen()`.  Creating functions like this help make your code clear and maintainable  Example `size_t ks_strlen(const char *s) { size_t i = 0; while (s[i]) i++; return i; }`

Comment: I accounted for the total string length when I created stringCharCount, no?

Comment: @karan satia 1) `stringCharCount` is limited to 1000 2) Code in the `for (int i = 0; i <= stringCharCount; i++) { ...` is questionable so its hard to understand coding goals.  3) I would have expected `char *tempWord = malloc(stringCharCount + 1);`

Comment: I allocated memory for *tempWord just before the first for loop. I didn't need to give it the +1 to account for a null value because tempWord stores, at most, ONE of the country names (never all of them). None of the country names are longer than 7 bytes. Whenever I encounter a comma while iterating over the original string, I dump the contents of tempWord into the final array at a specified index and reinitialize tempWord. This way, I can start fresh and add a new word to tempWord. It will, at most, store 7 characters.

Answer (score 0):

There are more bugs than lines in your code.

I'd suggest you start with something much simpler.

Work through a basic programming book with excercises.

**Edit**

Or, if this is about learning to program, try another, simpler programming language:

In `C#` your task looks rather simple:

```
string givenString = "USA,Canada Mexico,Bermuda.Grenada,Belize";
string [] words = string.Split(new char[] {' ', ',', '.'});
foreach(word in words)
    Console.WriteLine(word);
```

As you see, there are much issues to worry about:

- No memory management (alloc/free) this is handeled by the Garbage Collector
- no pointers, so nothing can go wrong with them
- powerful builtin string capabilities like `Split()`
- `foreach` makes loops much simpler

Comment: This about learning to program. I'll be moving to Objective-C in a month or so, but for right now, I HAVE to code in C.

Comment: The goal is to understand algorithm development, which in this case prohibits me from using built in functions that I'll undoubtedly be using later.